# Reuse of robotframework scripts in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, robotframework

We are using Robot Framework for Automation scripting and for performance testing in Jmeter. Just wanted to know anybody has done anything to reuse the RobotFramework script in JMeter for load testing. The main intention of this query is to avoid scripting twice for the same scenarios and to reusability of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Integrating `Robot Framework` in `JMeter` seems to be difficult.

However, you can integrate `JMeter` in `Robot Framework` using **JmeterLibrary**.

Check below links :

- [Installation Method](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robotframework-jmeterlibrary/1.0)
- [Example](https://github.com/kowalpy/Robot-Framework-JMeter-Library/blob/master/jmeterLibExample.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Using jmeter in RobotFramework is not very useful if the purpose is to reuse the RF scripts developped for acceptance testing.

You need jmeter scripts when using JmeterLibrary, which is precisely what I would like to avoid too.

I've heard of load testing using RF scripts thanks to selenium grid, but I don't have the details.